# Selenium Error while launching browser

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I am facing two issues with Selenium.

1.- Error while launching browser on windows -->  Example::testMyTestCase

Issues while capturing the screenshot:

```
Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 
   'http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/': 
    ERROR Server Exception: sessionId should not be null; 
has this session been started yet?

Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 
   'http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/': 
   Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser
```

2.- I have used Selenium on Linux. While running the code with PHPunit, the browser windows opened get closed automatically. I need to watch the log details after the execution. Is there any setting required for this?

Comment: Which Selenium version are you using? And how are you starting the selenium server?

Comment: Selenium version: selenium-server-1.0.3

And we are using batch file with command : java -jar selenium-server.jar –browserSessionReuse

Comment: For issue 1 :- Seems like you are closing the selenium session before taking the screenshot For issue 2 - You can pass the -log parameter while starting selenium to write log to a file

Answer (score 0):

Please try to execute this script using latest Selenium-Server.jar (selenium-server-standalone-2.23.1.jar)